# Having trouble reading a message body from a file in characters

Tags: python, python-2.7, python-3.x

```
def MsgBody(count = Counter()):
    file = open('mbox.txt')
    count = 0
    for line in file: #Read every line in file
        if line.startswith('X-DSPAM-Probability:'): #MessageEnd
            words = line.split() # split words
            for words in file:
                if line.startswith('From'): #MessageStart
                    for i in words:
                        count += len(i)
    return count
```

I don’t know why it keeps returning a 0, I figured it would at least return a number. My thought process was to use a for loop to read every line in the file, if the line starts with  ‘X-DSPAM-Probability’ it would catch and split the words. Use another for loop to read all the words and once a line starts with ‘From’ it would catch and use another for loop to read all the chars and then it would add to the counter. I’m not sure what to do.

Comment: In the 2nd for loop you are checking `if line.startswith('From')` shouldnt it be the `if words.startswith('From')` ? Because right now the 2nd `if` is never going to execute.

Comment: Yes! thank you it worked I appreciate it very much

Comment: Also, your function body is not indented properly. Not sure if that's a copy-paste issue, or a problem with your actual code.

Comment: One big problem is that you're trying to iterate through the file at the same time twice — and the inner-most `for` loop will take precedence and read all but the first line of the file leaving nothing for the outer `for` to process.

Comment: once you split the first line to "words", then how can you use the same variable in the second for loop? it'll overwrite the prev operation since both are local (closures)